# Не записывает в файл .txt но ошибок нет

Tags: python, json, запись, dump, txt

У меня есть код:

```
r='Paper.txt'
js1={}
js1['0']=[45,2,'South',78,time.time()]
json.dump((js1),open(r,"w"))
```

Почему то, спустя два года он перестал работать. Ошибок не выдает, но и не записывает ничего в .txt.

Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: У меня всё работает на `Python 3.8`.

Comment: А у меня почему-то не хочет после двух лет работы ): Python 3.6.4

Comment: @Denzel, а вы файл закрыли после записи? PS безопаснее использовать `context manager` - `with open(...) as f: json.dum(js1, f)`

Comment: @MaxU Нет, не закрывал. Ваш способ тоже не записывает.

Comment: закрытие никак не повлияло

Comment: попробуйте прочитать записанный файл при помощи Python скрипта - похоже файл записывается, но не в ту директорию, где вы его ожидаете

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Во-первых укажите полный путь к файлу дабы избежать сюрпризов (файл может записываться не в ту директорию, где вы его ожидаете увидеть):

  ```
  filename = r"c:\temp\Paper.txt"
  ```

при работе с неполными путями убедитесь, что интерпретатор запускается / работает в нужной директории:

```
print(os.path.abspath(os.curdir))      # показать текущую директорию
os.chdir(r"c:\some\target\directory")  # сменить текущую директорию
```

- Во-вторых используйте контекстный менеджер при работе с файлами - он сам позаботится о своевременном закрытии файла:

  ```
  with open(filename, "w") as f:
      json.dump(js1, f)
  ```

Comment: Вы оказались правы. Он не туда записывал. Однако мне остается неясным. Почему он поменял директорию. Никто этот скрипт уже давно не трогал.

Comment: @Denzel Сохраняет в ту директорию, из которой Вы запускаете файл.

Comment: Питон и все файлы находятся на диске D, а записывать он стал на диск E.

Comment: @Denzel как запускали раньше и как сейчас?

Comment: Да так же как и раньше, через консоль. Единственное, что поменялось - это на днях были перепады напряжения. И в итоге электричество пропало ночью(вырубило компьютер). Может из-за этого?